# Don't count the passenger once took a bus

Tags: postgresql

What is missing from this query?
It should count the passengers who could take the bus but once took the first bus they can't take the next one:

```
SELECT b.id, COUNT(p.id) AS passengers_on_board
FROM buses b
LEFT JOIN
  passengers p ON
    b.origin = p.origin AND
    b.destination = p.destination AND
    b.time >= p.time AND
    p.time <= '23:59'
GROUP BY
  b.id
ORDER BY
  b.id ASC;
```

---

Example:

Given tables:

buses:

```
   id | origin | destination | time
  ----+--------+-------------+-------
   10 | Warsaw | Berlin      | 10:55
   20 | Berlin | Paris       | 06:20
   21 | Berlin | Paris       | 14:00
   22 | Berlin | Paris       | 21:40
   30 | Paris  | Madrid      | 13:30
```

passengers:

```
   id | origin     | destination  | time
  ----+------------+--------------+-------
   1  | Paris      | Madrid       | 13:30
   2  | Paris      | Madrid       | 13:31
   10 | Warsaw     | Paris        | 10:00
   11 | Warsaw     | Berlin       | 22:31
   40 | Berlin     | Paris        | 06:15
   41 | Berlin     | Paris        | 06:50
   42 | Berlin     | Paris        | 07:12
   43 | Berlin     | Paris        | 12:03
   44 | Berlin     | Paris        | 20:00
```

your query should return:

```
 id | passengers_on_board
  ----+---------------------
   10 | 0
   20 | 1
   21 | 3
   22 | 1
   30 | 1
```

(row 3: got ('21', '4'), expected ('21', '3'))

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck not counting the passengers who already took a bus. They should not be counted again.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't do what you assumed. It lists buses with all passengers that could possibly get on them. There's nothing in the query that would stop a passenger from taking a a 14:00 Berlin-Paris, then again a 21:40 Berlin-Paris.

You can add an [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to see not only how many, but also which passengers exactly were counted for each bus. It shows passengers 40-43 taking both of these trips: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xKqk5cxk)

```sql
SELECT b.id bus_id, 
       COUNT(p.id) AS passenger_count_on_board, 
       ARRAY_AGG(p.id) AS passengers_on_board
FROM buses b
LEFT JOIN
  passengers p ON
    b.origin = p.origin AND
    b.destination = p.destination AND
    b.time >= p.time AND
    p.time <= '23:59'
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY b.id ASC;

-- bus_id | passenger_count_on_board | passengers_on_board
----------+--------------------------+---------------------
--     10 |                        0 | {NULL}
--     20 |                        1 | {40}
--     21 |                        4 | {40,41,42,43}
--     22 |                        5 | {44,40,41,42,43}
--     30 |                        1 | {1}
```

To fix it, you can flip this around and ask each passenger to select the nearest bus they can, then count how many times each bus was picked. You can again use `array_agg()` and this time just pick the first bus they were paired with: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BxEwUzwT)

```sql
WITH buses_selected_by_passengers AS (
SELECT p.id as passenger,
       (ARRAY_AGG(b.id ORDER BY b.time ASC))[1] as first_available_bus
FROM buses b left join passengers p on 
    b.origin = p.origin AND
    b.destination = p.destination AND
    b.time >= p.time AND
    p.time <= '23:59'
GROUP BY passenger
ORDER BY p.id ASC
)
select first_available_bus,
       count(passenger) AS passengers_on_board
from buses_selected_by_passengers
group by first_available_bus
ORDER BY first_available_bus ASC;
-- first_available_bus | passengers_on_board
-----------------------+---------------------
--                  10 |                   0
--                  20 |                   1
--                  21 |                   3
--                  22 |                   1
--                  30 |                   1
```

Which is equivalent to a `distinct on`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RmNQ_IjM)

```sql
WITH buses_selected_by_passengers AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id) 
       p.id as passenger,
       b.id as nearest_bus_selected
FROM buses b left join passengers p on 
    b.origin = p.origin AND
    b.destination = p.destination AND
    b.time >= p.time AND
    p.time <= '23:59'
ORDER BY p.id ASC, 
         b.time ASC 
)
SELECT nearest_bus_selected,
       count(passenger) AS passengers_on_board
FROM buses_selected_by_passengers
GROUP BY nearest_bus_selected
ORDER BY nearest_bus_selected ASC;
```

- [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) picks out only the first bus for each passenger (ordered along the `order by time asc`, so earliest first, so earliest only) - it's generally faster than `(array_agg())[1]` because it doesn't have to aggregate all of them first
- [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH) is a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), but you could use a regular [sub-select](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) just the same
- `count(passenger)` yields `0` for those buses that were not selected by anyone, because those buses are listed only thanks to `left join`, and their (un)matched `passenger` will be `null`. A `count(bus_id)` would count even the unselected buses, [`count(*)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.9.1.1.1) just counts rows, not things in them.